# How is the direction of the electric field encoded in the QFT of photons?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, dipole

Take a dipole receiving antenna(or visible light polarization filter), the receiving electrons are accelerated perpendicular to the incoming photons.

How is this encoded in QFT?
From wikipedia it appears to be from the relative polarizations:
[Wikipedia showing vector potential as a sum of many photons](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_of_the_electromagnetic_field#Electromagnetic_field_and_vector_potential)

But if it is encoded in the polarization of the many photons, would rotating the antenna 90' preserve the relative spins(right or left) and yet have less power transmitted and a perpendicular E field? Also if only due to polarization how does the spin affect the direction of the electrons?

Comment: Related, how to encode linear polarization in the xy plane for z moving photon. I was cobfused that polarization orientation described as a rank 1 tensor but it is complex valued so not as simple as right and left handed
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/374272/explanation-of-the-linear-polarization-from-the-photon-spin